# Diagnose mystery WM_PAINT message

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have a mystery WM_PAINT message being sent to a window for no reason that I can fathom. I am sending one WM_PAINT message from some code of mine using-

```
InvalidateRgn(graphwin_hwnd,NULL,1);
SendMessage(graphwin_hwnd,WM_PAINT,0,0);
```

but after executing the subsequent code that draws some graphics on the screen, the debugger indicates that a second WM_PAINT message arrives from somewhere. My question is, how can I diagnose what is causing this second WM_PAINT message to be sent.

**Edit:** i486 has correctly pointed out that I didn't need to explicitly do the SendMessage()... but to my surprise, even when I commented it out, I still get 1 excess mystery WM_PAINT message being sent to the handler for my graphics window, so it's not quite problem solved yet.

**Edit:** Oops, I was mistaken, after commenting out the SendMessage it seems I still had an unrelated bug screwing things up - but I did only get one WM_PAINT message... so problem solved.

Comment: Why did you decide to send `WM_PAINT` yourself? That is always wrong.

Comment: *I still get 1 excess mystery WM_PAINT message being sent to the handler for my graphics window, so it's not quite problem solved yet.* You should expect to receive `WM_PAINT` messages. Why are your surprised to receive them? How will your window paint without them?

Comment: @David, I expect to get one WM_PAINT message... but I get two. The drawing takes a while because it is a scatter graph containing over 100,000 points, I don't want to draw it twice unnecessarily.

Comment: @Mick To solve this problem you may draw your image in memory bitmap and repaint the window on WM_PAINT from that bitmap, not directly paint 100,000 points.

Comment: Unless you are using remote debugging, don't assume that a debugger will be completely transparent to the debuggee. When you break into the debugger, the debuggee will lose foreground acitivation, which commonly generates addition `WM_PAINT` messages. If you are going for local debugging, make sure to use a trace point instead of a breakpoint.

Comment: Or try with `OutputDebugString` in `WM_PAINT` and see real number of messages.

Comment: @IInspectable: That's why you **always** use two monitors when debugging GUI code. IDE on one monitor, app on the other, no interference.

Comment: **The number (and order) of `WM_PAINT` messages is *never* guaranteed.** Count on getting lots of them. Your code should not be breaking if you get more than one. What happens if the user switches to another app while you're in the middle of running your code?

Comment: @MSalters: Input focus is virtualized **per session**, not per display. Adding displays doesn't do anything to prevent input focus from switching to the IDE, when you hit a breakpoint. You absolutely need 2 interactive user sessions (e.g. by running a virtual machine) to prevent any interference.

Comment: @i486: There is no need to add debugging output code. A tracepoint can be instructed to output arbitrary text (see [Tracepoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/10/tracepoints.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable This seems like C#. I am not sure it exists in C/Win32 and we don't know the VS version of Mick. `OutputDebugString` is the good old method :)

Comment: @i486: Tracepoints were introduced in VS 2005 (a **decade** ago). And they work with native code just as well, as can be easily verified. Modifying code so that it does, what the debugger can do without modifications and recompiling/linking, has nothing going for it.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, but with `OutputDebugString` you can get debug/diagnostic/trace messages without running VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send WM_PAINT - it is sent automatically after Invalidate. Call `UpdateWindow` to force it. Probably the second WM_PAINT is because of `InvalidateRgn`. To test this, comment your `SendMessage` and check for WM_PAINT.

Comment: Thanks for that... but seems I have more than one cock up! See edit.

Comment: I hope the extra WM_PAINT is after the initial repainting, i.e. you get one normal WM_PAINT when window is first displayed, other from `InvalidateRgn` and the phantom message is 3rd?