# Closing a Window by handle

Tags: c++, windows, function, winapi, window

I wrote an application in C++ that detects Windows with a certain title and puts them in a list.

Is there a way to simply close a Window by using it's handle?

I've tried [CloseWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632678(v=vs.85).aspx) but it only minimized the window.

I've also tried [DestroyWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) but it didn't have any effect on the window at all..

Hope someone can help

Comment: Try `SendMessage` referring to the window's handle with a `WM_CLOSE` message. `DestroyWindow` only works from the thread which created the window, according to the documentation you linked.

Comment: `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, nullptr, nullptr);`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: Sending `WM_CLOSE` to a window sends a **request** to close the window. The window procedure can handle the `WM_CLOSE` message, popping up confirmation dialogs, or ignoring it altogether. This may turn out to be a problem for whatever you are trying to implement.

Comment: On the other hand, most users would appreciate the ability to cancel when faced with the "Exit without saving?" dialog. `WM_CLOSE` is the correct solution.

Comment: @MSalters: How is a solution, that occasionally fails to work altogether supposedly *"the correct solution"*?

Comment: @IInspectable: Because the alternative, one that occasionally destroys hours of work, is far, _far_ worse.

Comment: @MSalters: Are you a mind reader? Or is this a case of *"There are only two opinions: My opinion and the wrong opinion."*? At any rate, reading [comments like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34811431/1889329#comment57368096_34811431) keeps reminding me, that when you get things wrong, you get them very, *very* wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable: Raymond Chen famously quipped about psychic debugging. In reality, that's just a lot of experience. There _are_ people who need to consider how to deal with rogue applications, yes, but out of that group 100% are familiar with how `WM_CLOSE` work.

Comment: @MSalters: There is no way to know, how `WM_CLOSE` *"works"*. Handling of this message is private to any given application, compiled into its executable image. You may understand, that applications can respond to `WM_CLOSE`, but you will never know how any given application deals with this message specifically (you certainly cannot know this about future applications). The point is simple: Sending `WM_CLOSE` may or may not be the appropriate solution. This depends on the requirements, which the OP has not specified.

Comment: @IInspectable Why so confrontational?